# HTML Forms: Confused with the required attribute

Tags: html, forms, post

```
 <form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" required>
   <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

If I have a code like this with method ="post". I'm confused about the required attribute. What is true in this case?

1. "Required" attribute will check if the text field is empty in the server side when the form is submitted.
2. "Required" attribute will check if the text field is empty in the client side when the form is submitted.
3. submit button can be clicked even if the text field is empty.

Comment: 2 -submit can be effective **only** if input **is not** empty. it has nothing to do with a post or get method, nor with a server

Comment: Client side validation which one can bypass by modifying html code in inspect mode. We use this keyword just to prevent form submission with invalid state. You must validate your form fields at server side also